# How is/can back- and frontend be separated in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am evaluating frameworks and I would like to understand Ruby on Rails architecture better.

Coming form a Java background I developed components separately namely front and backend. More concretely for my backend I use Dropwizard and start a HTTP server. For the front end I use a nginx webserver with some forwarding to connected to my backend api via REST with Json objects. The front end is just plain html and a little JavaScript in vue.js.

Now I am very new to the ruby philosophy and I am quite unsure how Ruby accomplishes the task of separating front and backend. I read some some notes refering to rails-api that can create a HTTP server. But I am still unsure if and how ruby and rails builds this stack.

I would be glad if someone could explain Ruby on Rails architecture a little bit and maybe point to some tutorials how to accomplish a project with the stack above. Moreover is the stack I used to build in -as mentioned with Java above - even the Ruby way?

Comment: It depends if you're using Rails + conventional HTML and JavaScript or Rails + JSON API + a front-end framework like React or Angular.

Comment: So if I choose the latter option Rails + JSON API + a front-end with vue.js. What would be the ruby way.

Answer (score 1):

Right now rails-api has been deprecated and merged back into the Rails core. You can use standard Rails to build API routes similar to Dropwizard and then have a frontend framework, like Vue, pull the data using Ajax. You will still use a reverse proxy in front of the Ruby app like nginx so that is no different than Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify  as Rails API is integrated into Rails can I just build a backend with a RESTful API? and how does Ajax play a role in this architecture I thought that if Rails is my backend it handles all the connection to a database and just hands data over to the front end via REST and Json object.

Comment: REST or GraphQL are both common options here for data-exchange from your client-side application to Rails. Using the API helper is not strictly necessary but may make your implementation easier, so it's worth at least trying it to see if it helps.

Comment: You can just build a REST API using Rails. Ajax is just the term used for accessing an API from your client JavaScript. Definitely look at the Ruby on Rails documentation and check for the API mode link.